# Remove adjacent items group in list based on length of elements

Tags: python, text-processing, pdftotext

I have a list of items from PDF text extraction in this way:

```
['performed three times. Data represent the mean±SEM of threeindependent experiments. *P<0.05, **P<0.005, ***P<0.001.', 'B','O-GlcNAc', 'AMPK', 'pAMPK', 'SREBP-1', 'ACC', 'FAS', 'actin', 'C','T', 'L', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'T', 'M', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'D', 'O', 'N','T', 'M', 'G', 'HaCaT HeLa', 'O', '-G', 'lN', 'A', 'c', 'le', 'v','e', 'l', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L','0.0', '2.5', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O','N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '**', '***', 'S','R', 'E', 'B', 'P', '-1', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a','T', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a','T', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0','F', 'A', 'S', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T','L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O','N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', 'A', 'C', 'C','(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '2.5','1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'a','C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', 'O', '-G', 'lc', 'N', 'A', 'c','le', 'v', 'e', 'l', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T','L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N','H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '***', '***', 'S', 'R', 'E','B', 'P', '-1', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T','L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N','H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '***', 'F', 'A', 'S', '(A','.U', ')', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0','0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T','M', 'G', '2.0', '***', 'A', 'C', 'C', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'e', 'L','a', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a','D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '***', '***','***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '*** ***', '***', 'O-GlcNAc','AMPK', 'pAMPK', 'SREBP-1', 'ACC', 'FAS', '�-actin', 'O', '-G', 'lN','A', 'c', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', '(A', '.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H','a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r','H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.0','Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'p', 'A', 'M', 'P', 'K', '(A','.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5','1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T','L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.5 ***', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L','a', 'S', 'R', 'E', 'B', 'P', '-1', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'C', 'T','L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u','e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a','**', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'A', 'C', 'C', '(A','.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5','1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T','L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.0', '***', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e','L', 'a', 'F', 'A', 'S', '(A', '.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a','C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H','a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '***', 'Q','u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.0', '***', '*** ***', '*','******* *******', 'HaCaT HeLa', 'CTL Quer CTL Quer', 'A', 'Fig. 4.Quercetin regulates SREBP­1 and its target proteins']
```

In this list, I would like to remove all groups of adjacent elements (`length of group > N`) for which no element has `length > M`.

A pseudo code would be:

```py
     for item in list:
         if len(item) <= M:
             buffer.append(item_index)
             active = True
         if len(item) > M and active == True:
             active = False
             if len(buffer) > N:
                 list.replace_at_index(buffer_by_index,'')
             buffer.clear()
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you clarify "adjacent elements", N and M???  Suggest providing some psuedo process code...

Comment: What does *adjacent* have to do with it? What if there's only one element?

Comment: If there is one element, then N = 0. Then if len(buffer) > 0, if will clear that single element. But if N =3, then it will clear if len(buffer) > 3. And those elements have to be adjacent in the list (so index i, i+1, i+2, i+n with n = N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use the built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method to iterate through the elements in a list alongside each element's index:

```
lst = ['performed three times. Data represent the mean±SEM of threeindependent experiments. *P<0.05, **P<0.005, ***P<0.001.', 'B','O-GlcNAc', 'AMPK', 'pAMPK', 'SREBP-1', 'ACC', 'FAS', 'actin', 'C','T', 'L', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'T', 'M', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'D', 'O', 'N','T', 'M', 'G', 'HaCaT HeLa', 'O', '-G', 'lN', 'A', 'c', 'le', 'v','e', 'l', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L','0.0', '2.5', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O','N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '**', '***', 'S','R', 'E', 'B', 'P', '-1', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a','T', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a','T', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0','F', 'A', 'S', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T','L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O','N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', 'A', 'C', 'C','(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '2.5','1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'a','C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', 'O', '-G', 'lc', 'N', 'A', 'c','le', 'v', 'e', 'l', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T','L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N','H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '***', '***', 'S', 'R', 'E','B', 'P', '-1', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T','L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N','H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '***', 'F', 'A', 'S', '(A','.U', ')', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0','0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T','M', 'G', '2.0', '***', 'A', 'C', 'C', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'e', 'L','a', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a','D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '***', '***','***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '*** ***', '***', 'O-GlcNAc','AMPK', 'pAMPK', 'SREBP-1', 'ACC', 'FAS', '�-actin', 'O', '-G', 'lN','A', 'c', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', '(A', '.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H','a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r','H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.0','Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'p', 'A', 'M', 'P', 'K', '(A','.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5','1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T','L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.5 ***', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L','a', 'S', 'R', 'E', 'B', 'P', '-1', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'C', 'T','L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u','e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a','**', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'A', 'C', 'C', '(A','.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5','1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T','L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.0', '***', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e','L', 'a', 'F', 'A', 'S', '(A', '.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a','C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H','a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '***', 'Q','u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.0', '***', '*** ***', '*','******* *******', 'HaCaT HeLa', 'CTL Quer CTL Quer', 'A', 'Fig. 4.Quercetin regulates SREBP­1 and its target proteins']

N = 3
M = 5

buffer = []
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    if len(v) <= M:
        buffer.append(i)
    else:
        if len(buffer) > N:
            for i in buffer:
                lst[i] = None
        buffer.clear()

print(list(filter(None, lst)))
```

Output:

```
['performed three times. Data represent the mean±SEM of threeindependent experiments. *P<0.05, **P<0.005, ***P<0.001.', 'B', 'O-GlcNAc', 'AMPK', 'pAMPK', 'SREBP-1', 'HaCaT HeLa', '*** ***', '***', 'O-GlcNAc', 'AMPK', 'pAMPK', 'SREBP-1', 'ACC', 'FAS', '�-actin', '2.5 ***', '*** ***', '*', '******* *******', 'HaCaT HeLa', 'CTL Quer CTL Quer', 'A', 'Fig. 4.Quercetin regulates SREBP\xad1 and its target proteins']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear exactly what is desired.   Below is some code of what I believe is being asked for.   Hope this helps. If this is off... let me know.

Psuedo algorithm

1. Given a list of strings.
2. Identify the len of each string using class cntseq.
3. Identify sequence of strings having the same len
4. For each sequence, if the length of sequence

```
    x = ['performed three times. Data represent the mean±SEM of three independent experiments. P<0.05, P<0.005, P<0.001.', 'B', 'O-GlcNAc', 'AMPK', 'pAMPK', 'SREBP-1', 'ACC', 'FAS', 'actin', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'T', 'M', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'T', 'M', 'G', 'HaCaT HeLa', 'O', '-G', 'lN', 'A', 'c', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '2.5', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '', '', 'S', 'R', 'E', 'B', 'P', '-1', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', 'F', 'A', 'S', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', 'A', 'C', 'C', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '2.5', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', 'O', '-G', 'lc', 'N', 'A', 'c', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '', '', 'S', 'R', 'E', 'B', 'P', '-1', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '', 'F', 'A', 'S', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '', 'A', 'C', 'C', '(A', '.U', ')', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'C', 'T', 'L', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'D', 'O', 'N', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'T', 'M', 'G', '2.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '* ', '', 'O-GlcNAc', 'AMPK', 'pAMPK', 'SREBP-1', 'ACC', 'FAS', '�-actin', 'O', '-G', 'lN', 'A', 'c', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', '(A', '.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.0', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'p', 'A', 'M', 'P', 'K', '(A', '.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.5 ', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'S', 'R', 'E', 'B', 'P', '-1', 'le', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'A', 'C', 'C', '(A', '.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.0', '', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', 'F', 'A', 'S', '(A', '.U', ')', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', '0.0', '1.5', '1.0', '0.5', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'a', 'C', 'a', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'H', 'e', 'L', 'a', '2.0', '', '* ', '', '***** *******', 'HaCaT HeLa', 'CTL Quer CTL Quer', 'A', 'Fig. 4. Quercetin regulates SREBP\xad1 and its target proteins']
    df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['v'])
    df['len'] = df.v.apply(len)
    N = 2
    M = 2
    class cntseq(object):
        '''
        Define class to track sequences across the Column
        '''
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.prevLen = -1
            self.cnt = 0
            self.start = None

        def countN(self, r):

            if r.len == self.prevLen:
                # if adjcent sequence found, mark it's start with "len.start"
                self.cnt += 1
                if self.start == None : 
                    self.start = int(r.name)-1
                return '%d.%d'%(r.len, self.start)
            else:
                # non-adjcent sequence found, mark None.None"
                self.prevLen = r.len
                self.cnt = 0
                self.start = None
                return 'None.None'
    
    # Identify sequences of adjcent lengths.
    cs = cntseq()
    df['seq'] = df.apply(lambda r : cs.countN(r),axis=1)

    print("\nOriginal DF info")
    print(df.describe())
    print("\nOriginal DF ")
    print(df.head())

    # Compute lookup of duplicate information
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('seq').seq.count())
    df2.columns=['M']
    df2 = df2.reset_index()

    n = df2[df2.seq == 'None.None'].index[0]
    df2 = df2.drop(78, axis=0)

    print("\nLookup DF, seq has count and index for start of 'adjcent elements'")
    print(df2.head())

    # Compute final DF without duplicates
    df3 = df[df.seq.isin(list(df2[df2.M > M].seq))].head()
    print("\nFinal DF without duplicated")
    print(df3)

    print("\nOriginal DF info")
    print(df3.describe())

output:

    Original DF info
                  len
    count  578.000000
    mean     1.730104
    std      5.284275
    min      0.000000
    25%      1.000000
    50%      1.000000
    75%      1.000000
    max    110.000000

    Original DF 
                                                       v  len        seq
    0  performed three times. Data represent the mean...  110  None.None
    1                                                  B    1  None.None
    2                                           O-GlcNAc    8  None.None
    3                                               AMPK    4  None.None
    4                                              pAMPK    5  None.None

    Lookup DF, seq has count and index for start of 'adjcent elements'
         seq  M
    0  0.221  1
    1  0.325  6
    2   0.70  1
    3  1.111  2
    4  1.116  8

    Final DF without duplicated
        v  len  seq
    10  T    1  1.9
    11  L    1  1.9
    12  D    1  1.9
    13  O    1  1.9
    14  N    1  1.9

    Original DF info
           len
    count  5.0
    mean   1.0
    std    0.0
    min    1.0
    25%    1.0
    50%    1.0
    75%    1.0
    max    1.0
```

Comment: Well thank you for this alternative way of doing it :). However 3. was not necessary. Would have been: identify sequence of strings having the same or LESS len (with len cutoff given). Sorry if my question was unclear.